# PHP IF function checking more than one statement/argument

Tags: php, if-statement

What is the best practice when using the **if()** function in PHP when one wants to check more than ONE statement/argument?

Example:

```
if ( isset($string) && empty($string2) {
 code
}
```

**or** should it instead be:

```
if ( (isset($string)) && (empty($sting2)) ) {
 code
}
```

Comment: No need for the extra parenthesis... I'd leave them out.  However, I tend to add them when order of operation comes into play, just to be explicit how I want things grouped.

Comment: Either way works, I personally use the extra parentheses to organize my code a but more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example I would not use second set of parenthesis.

Extra parenthesis are needed when condition logic is a bit more complicated, like, for example:

```
if ( (isset($string) || isset($strstr)) && empty($sting2) ) {
  code
}
```